# How to create responsive text in bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-4

can anyone pls help me in responsive text using Bootstrap 4. I searched everywhere but wierd to see no tutorial in this regard. Here are my codes in case if you want to guide me.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div style="font-size: 3rem;">Hello World</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! Now what's your *question*?

Comment: What's happening? What do you expect to happen? Give us an [mcve]

Comment: Please change your title to describe the problem or question. Also, please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: If that's literally *all* of your code, you've forgotten to include Bootstrap, and you've forgotten the all-important viewport meta tag.

Comment: @csmckelvey i don't think there's need to change title since there're many newbies like me think in a same way.

Comment: Fine, I did it instead.

Comment: @csmckelvey, you pros know better. i just expressed my view re title and in result i got -27 resulting suspension for days to "ask" another question. probably a way to welcome a newbie by a pro.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, this is described in the [Responsive typography](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/typography/#responsive-typography) section of the Bootstrap 4 documentation. From the docs: **Bootstrap doesn’t do this for you, but it’s fairly easy to add if you need it.**

It is indeed not that hard. Basically you have to define the font sizes on the `<html>` tag for each media breakpoint.

Here is an example:

```css
html { font-size: 1rem; }

@media (min-width: 576px) {
    html { font-size: 1.25rem; }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    html { font-size: 1.5rem; }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    html { font-size: 1.75rem; }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    html { font-size: 2rem; }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: ah you have made my life - you guided in a very easiest way. Thanks from a newbie.

Comment: seems like it was easier for me to just use  `font-size: 9vw; letter-spacing: 4vw;` for my needs